# laravel-7 elequent collection merge not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm trying to return an eloquent collection in my function so I did this:

```
// model
// User.php
// user -> branch -> groups -> alerts

public function alerts()
    {
        $alerts = (new Alert)->newCollection(); // empty elequent collection
        $groups = $this->branch()->first()->groups()->get(); // collection of group model
        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            // merge all groups alerts to an single eloquent collection
            $alerts->merge($group->alerts()->get());
        }
        return $alerts;
    }
```

however, I know some there are data in my database and I checked them. `$alerts` in my case must not be empty!

and if I `dd($alerts)` there is only an `empty` set of eloquent collection.

```
// dd($alerts)
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1423 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

also I'm aware of `push` and `concat` methods but `concat` also is not working, and `push` doesn't do what I want.

I know I can do join tables but dont want use joins too.

how do I merge eloquent collections properly?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $alerts = $alerts->merge($group->alerts()->get());
}
```

You forgot to assign the merged collection.

Comment: nice, it didn't notice the assignment! silly mistake haha.

Comment: mistake happens ;)

Comment: I did the same mistake and it took an hour to figure this out! Phew!

Comment: I could locate this question only when I tried to ask same question. Asking questions is good!! :)